# I can't put an applet in google chrome or safari

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome, safari, applet

I am learning HTML and I am trying to put my applet in my HTML file. When I open it with firefox, it works perfectly, but when I try to open it with chrome or safari it fails.  Chrome says:

```
load: class Main.class not found.
```

Here is the tag I am using:

```
<applet code="Main.class" width="500" height="500"></applet>
```

I have put the Main.class in the same folder as the HTML file.
I'm running a mac, but i tried it on another computer running windows 7 and it worked with chrome.

Help!  Is my mac haunted?

I am running the java version 1.6.0_33 from apple inc

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the html code this way

```
<applet code="Main" width="500" height="500"></applet>
```

---

Report if that helped

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but still doesnt work. It says:load: class Main not found.

Comment: Do you have JRE installed on your mac?

Comment: *"Report that helps"*  Second time I've seen that, and it makes no sense.  It is usually 'Hope that helps'.  The only thing I could think 'Report that helps' to mean is that one person is instructing a 2nd to tell a 3rd 'That helps'.